# Photoshop CS6 - automatize procedures

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm not a designer but I need some PS usage for creating my android app. I have about 100 .png pictures and I need to do the same procedure with all of them: cut off 50px from the bottom and from the top of each picture. That would be a huge waste of time to do it manually so is there any way to automatize this action? Any macros or scripts..? Thanks

Comment: also @Maver1ck try searching [batch](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=batch) or [Image Processor](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=Image+Processor) in the upper right and we have past questions/answers that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It seemed too obvious for an answer, but I suppose it is ...*

[Record an action](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7448a.html) and then [batch apply it](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7427a.html).